# Lost myOpenID account and access: Here is the fix

Tags: support, openid

Tonight I completely lost my OpenID and credentials to sign in to stats.SE and math.SE. I was also unable to "recover" them via the "Recover" link on the myOpenID web sign-in and that site does not provide any support whatsoever.

Apparently, **[I'm not the only one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88451/lost-my-openid-account)**.

*I'm suspecting this will be happening to other stats.SE users and so this is why I'm posting this information here.*

The fix is to simply sign up again for an account with the exactly the same information as before. Without needing to do any additional confirmation, my credentials were reestablished and my SE accounts were linked to everything properly.

This bug is not Stack Overflow / Stack Exchange related as far as I know.

Comment: yep, we have some other plans in place for dealing with this. Very bizarre.

Answer (score 1):

As detailed in [this answer on Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88451/myopenid-account-mysteriously-vanished/88790#88790), MyOpenId had issues caused by the Amazon outage.  Once that outage was resolved, accounts were restored.

Comment: What is the "fix" in the works that @Jeff mentioned? While it was a "quick fix" to reregister, it's also disturbing since anyone else could have conceivably signed up in my place and taken control of my account.

Comment: @cardinal, absolutely - but that's a concern for MyOpenId.  The plans Jeff mentioned are still in the works and getting closer, but not ready just quite yet.

Comment: Sure, yes, I didn't intend to imply it was a SE/SO problem. That's why I was curious about progress on some other fix. ETA?

Comment: @cardinal, [6-8 weeks](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19514#19514)...soon. (: